# Making easy image gallery with php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, image-gallery

This code works, but it won't open the picture in real size when I click on it.

```
echo "<table>";
$res = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $mysqli->query($res);
    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
    {   
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"; ?><a href='./display_images2.php?showrealsize'> <img src="<?php echo $myRow["image"];  ?>" height="100" width="100"> </a> <?php echo "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>"; echo $myRow["name"]; echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    if(isset($_GET['showrealsize'])){
    echo $_GET[$myRow["image"]];
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't open the picture in real size". Are the pictures displayed in the first place?

Comment: Yes, they are displayed as 100 pixels. I want to open up them in real size by clicking.

Comment: You will need to use have some Javascript/JQuery in order to make an image gallery as you have described. PHP alone does not have any front-end functionality. It simply communicates with the server to retrieve the images and displays them on your page.

Comment: if I have something like,  echo "<img src=" echo $myRow["image"] >";   how would it be? But I dont know how to do it right exactly.

Comment: Since you are displaying the image in a table each cell will be identical to the others. In addition, PHP simply populates the src attribute, it does not do anything else. You will have to show some of your Javascript/JQuery that you tried before I can help you.

Comment: Thank you but it is a school work we are only allowed to use php and html.

Comment: Keep in mind 'On click' events are client-side functionality. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: I can make the pictures opens in a new window.

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking you wanted to open them in a modal. Give me a minute I will look it over.

Comment: Ran the code and it does take me to the href, what are you trying to do on the other page?

Comment: On other page, I will have the image and some image information. And allow users to click back to gallery.

Comment: The problem is I cant get  [$myRow["image"]  when the code is placed outside of the WHILE loop...

Comment: Okay now I understand the problem, you need to specify that in your post.

Comment: can you please tell me how do I get  [$myRow["image"]] from outside of the while loop? I am a beginner so I do not really know how to specify this. :) But I will understand the code.